# how to restrict the input size to certain length and not allow further chars in angular using reactive form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need to restrict the length of the input field to `10` and not allow further characters in the filed, without throwing the validation message. It should simply stop taking further characters, can you help me
and I don't want to use `maxlength = 10`

***html:***

```
<div class="col col-4">
{{ EditAddressContext.streetNumber }}:
<p>
<input type="text" name="streetNumber" formControlName="streetNumber" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && streetNumberError}" />
<small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="submitted && streetNumberError">
<small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="streetNumberError">
<small *ngFor="let error of streetNumberErrorArray">{{error}}<br></small>
</small>
</small>
</p>
</div>
```

***.ts file:***

```
formGeneration() {
    this.interceptEditAddressFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({      
      streetNumber: ['', [Validators.maxLength(11)]],
      streetPrefix: [],
      streetName: ['',],
      streetSuffix: [],
      streetType: [],
      roomSuite: []
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you want the input to be block, the best solution is the HTML maxlength attribute. There is no error message since it is not possible to write more characters... An other solution is blocking user input via JS, but ugly and less error-proof...

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to create a custom directive :

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMaxLength]'
})
export class MaxLengthDirective {

  constructor(private readonly formControl: FormControlName) {}

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(event): void {
    const value = this.formControl.value;

    if (value.length > 10) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

}
```

Add it on a field with a formControlName :

```html
<input type="text" appMaxLength formControlName="nameIt">
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a mask. This allow you to define what to expect in an input.

I suggest you use this librariry: [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)